# How does one create a DB data directory using a publish profile in VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

so basically we put our DB files in a DBName directory.
The issue I am having is to go and create the DBName directory manually everytime with a fresh install, I would like to be able to create the directory if it does not exist before the Create db scripts run. I have a SQL script to run at build but keep getting SQL70001 error.